# Replace the first word of every line in a file with the line number

Tags: text-processing, sed

If I have a file like this:

```
foo bar
bar foo
5 foo
bar 5
```

and I want to change the file to look like this:

```
1 bar
2 foo
3 foo
4 5
```

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about Awk?

```
$ awk '{$1 = FNR} 1' file
1 bar
2 foo
3 foo
4 5
```